# Different duality-correlations in holographic principle?

Tags: cosmology, information, ads-cft, holographic-principle, duality

I found an interesting article "Surface/State Correspondence as a Generalized Holography" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03542)

If I understood it well, the authors proposed this model to generalize the holographic principle to apply it to situations where no boundaries exist. According to this model, there could be a duality between two theories in the same number of dimensions.

Basically, my question is:

Could this model be applied to situations where two theories have different duality-correlations (to models where the amount of information in a volume is proportional to the the square of the surface area, or perhaps models where there is not general correlation at all)?

I contacted one of the authors and he said me that he think this was possible but he was not completely sure.

So do you have any idea? Could this model be applied to situations where two theories have different duality-correlations?

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are looking for. Entropy of spatial volume in nongravitational QFT goes with the volume, entropy of spatial volume in gravitational QFT goes with the surface area, so holographic duality can identify gravitational and nongravitational theories with different number of open dimensions, OK. You are looking for theories in which entropy/information of a volume goes with neither volume nor surface area, but according to some other law, and which are part of a holographic duality? Is that the exact question? Glenn Evenbly might have something like that.

Comment: @MitchellPorter that is interesting, do you have something specific? Maybe from that author (Glenn Evenbly)? Also, I was thinking that this model could be applied to theories that would not be necessarily dual

Comment: @MitchellPorter I mean, usually in holographic models we have a universe "A" (in the bulk) described by a theory which is dual to the theory describing universe "B" (in the boundary). Since the authors of the article that I put in my question proposed a model where there would be no need of having a boundary, I thought that it could be applied to models where  there are no duality between two theories/universes (e.g a model where in tha same space (bulk) we would have universe "A" described by a theory and universe "B" described by a fundamentally different theory)

Comment: @MitchellPorter sort of a holographic model but where theories would not have any relation between each other. Where theories would not be equivalent or even similar

Comment: If the theories "would not have any relation between each other"... then what is the question? Holographic duality is just a kind of relation, I thought you wanted to alter the relation somehow, but if you abolish all relation, I don't know what's left.

Comment: OK, I have a fuzzy idea of what you might be thinking. Miyaji and Takayanagi propose a correspondence between hypersurfaces in a quantum gravity theory, and quantum states in another, nongravitational theory. So perhaps you're asking whether that kind of correspondence could exist for theories which don't satisfy the template of "information goes with the volume in the gravitational theory, and with the surface area in the nongravitational theory"?

Comment: @MitchellPorter would it be valid to apply Miyaji's and Takayanagi's model in that case?